# Python Connection with mongoHQ fails?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongohq

I want to connect to mongoHq database through python.
here is what i have done so far

an environmental variable is set:

```
MONGOHQ_URL = mongodb://myusername:mypassword@paulo.mongohq.com:10084/mydb
```

and the app.py file

```
import os
import datetime
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
MONGO_URL = os.environ.get('MONGOHQ_URL')
client = MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
db = client.mydb
```

when i run this file following error comes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.6.2-py3.3-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 349, in __init__
self.__find_node(seeds)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.6.2-py3.3-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 750, in __find_node
raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\flaskk\test.py", line 9, in <module>
client = MongoClient(MONGO_URL)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.6.2-py3.3-win-    amd64.egg\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 352, in __init__
raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to localhost:27017: [WinError    10061] 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Please help !! Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I suspect that you are not passing the MONGOHQ_URL env variable properly. If you try `print MONGO_URL` i bet you'll get `None`

Answer (score 0):

I think , there is no need of setting environment variable for testing it in local machine , and maybe the error is because it didn't get set properly.

Another issue I can see , that you haven't replaced user and pass with your username password of user you created for particular database.Try connecting your mongo shell with that monhqurl by typing 
`mongo --username <user> --password <pass> --host <host> --port 28015` 
replacing it with your details .If it connects successfully then mongohqurl is correct

Comment: i actually replaced username and password !! That is not the issue

Comment: try this command , and check if it works  `mongo paulo.mongohq.com:10068/webchat -u <user> -p<password>`